# Trouble of understanding the concept of packages in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, package

A time ago I started learning Common Lisp, but now I have come to my first real stumbling block, understanding a concept. I started to change my learning projects to move from single file sources to packages. Everything so far went as expected, but then, I stumbled upon one file, a sudoku game I coded, that behaves other then I thought. You can find it here: https://github.com/Silberbogen/cl-sudoku

When I started (spiele-sudoku) after I switched inside the package via (in-package :cl-sudoku), everything works fine, but when I start it via (cl-sudoku:spiele-sudoku), only my input of coordinates is excepted, while any other input seems not to be interpreted.

What concept do I miss, so I could start the game via (cl-sudoku:spiele)?

Comment: It may or may not answer this question, but [The Complete Idiot’s Guide to Common Lisp Packages](http://www.flownet.com/gat/packages.pdf) tends to be a good, informative guide that a lot of people say clears up a lot of confusion for them.

Comment: I just downloaded it. Thanks a lot for the hint, Joshua!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `read-from-string` to read your input.  That will intern any word encountered as a symbol into the current package.

In your main function, you use `case` to compare with symbols, but those are interned into the `cl-sudoku` package.  So, if your current package is `cl-sudoku`, it will work, otherwise not.

You should not use `read` or `read-form-string` to parse user input (if you absolutely must, at least bind `*read-eval*` to nil).  Instead call `intern` yourself (possibly in combination `string-upcase`) to create symbols in the right package.  If you want to use package-independent symbols, intern them into the `KEYWORD` package, so that you can do `case` on keywords.

It might be helpful to use `ecase` or `ccase`, or at least log some debug information on invalid input.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, Svante. I used intern at first, but while searching for my mistake I changed it to read-from-string, in the hope I could find the bug. Now that I used ecase instead of case, I can see that my input is not, say HINWEIS, like I thought, but CL-SUDOKU::HINWEIS.
It seems, that I now have to learn how to intern them to the keyword package.
You helped me a lot, so, thank you very much!

Comment: @SaschaBiermanns: `intern` takes the package name as an additional parameter.

Comment: Done. Thank you, your answer solved my problem completely. I fixed my bugs and it works now.